# Flutter align widget in row in listview

Tags: flutter, listview, alignment, row

I have a listView with scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal and every item of the list is a column.

In every column there are some rows that contains various widgets.

I want to align the widgets in the row but I don't know how.

```
...
Expanded(
   child: ListView.separated(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      controller: scrollController,
      physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int colIndex) {
         return Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
               Row(
                  children: [
                     Text(
                       "Some text",
                       textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                     ),
                     IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.settings_rounded),
                     ),
                  ],
               ),
               Text(
                  "Some other text",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
               ),
            ],
         ),
      },
   ),
),
...
```

I'd like to have the Text("Some text") in the center of the row and the IconButton on the end (right) of the row.

I tried with Expanded, Align, Wrap, and other things that I found online but nothing helps me. The main problem seems to be that, due the the list not having a fixed width the row doesn't have one either, and this conflicts with the alignment tools that I tried.

Any idea?

Comment: You could use Stack widget for that, you can align freely in the center and align icons in the right, but Text can overflow or icon can, it depends on length of widject, and you are using 2 icons you can user Positioned for icons

Comment: Stack put a widget on top of the other so this works only if the dimension of text and icon are of the right size. In my idea the text could be 1 char or infinite and with stack this doesn't work

Comment: I think you want somthing like AppBar's centeredTitle? Yes appbar won't solve your problem, it's for example. It does center title and you can add actions (ex: [IconButton(),]) for 1, 2 or 3 and it will adjust for center or overflow ellipse. Can you write more about use case, feature of your UI and we could find another (UI/UX) solition for it.

Comment: Yes, appbar is similar to what I'd like. 
In appbar you can have the title on the center and the actions on the side.
I'd like to have the possibility to move the elements inside the row freely (text on center and icons on the left, text on the left and icons on the right, text on center and icons both on left and right, and so on) and without having to add the spacer() to have more elements to space with the axisAlignement

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [IntrinsicWidth](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicWidth-class.html) to wrap your `Column`. It  sizes its children to the maximum width. Then do whatewer needed in your `Row`. I tried a simple solution here in the code snippet, which is adding a `SizedBox()` as first child, and setting `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween`. But wrapping chlidren of the `Row` in `Align` would also work, as well as adding `Spacer`'s. I'm sure there's more options.

```
ListView.separated(
     scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
     separatorBuilder: (_,__)=>const VerticalDivider(),
     itemCount: 10,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int colIndex) {
         return IntrinsicWidth(
            child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
               Row(
                 mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    const SizedBox(),
                    const Text(
                       "Some text",
                     ),
                     IconButton(
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.settings_rounded),
                       onPressed: (){},
                     ),
                  ],
               ),
               const Text(
                  "Some other text. It's longer so we can see row elements alignments",
               ),
            ],
         )
         ) ;
      },
);
```

Please read the `IntrinsicWidth`'s description before using it. It's a rather heavy widget and affects performance.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't works. It allows me to align the two elements in the row with the "mainAxisAlignment" but I can't put them where I like (the first at the center of the row and the second at the end)

Comment: Please paste this exact code to Dartpad. Because I tested it. Maybe you're missing the 3rd element I agged to the Row? I added SizedBox before text. As I said, there's other ways to what you can do within the Row when the main issue (expanding the Row) is solved. I'll update my answer with more options when I have time. But please make sure you followed the current answer.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean that it doesn't work at all but that it doesn't solve my problem.
It does what you said, it allows you to align item inside the row using the mainAxisAlignment but I'd like to move freely the objects in the row.
In your code, for example, the text is not in the center of the row, because the 3 widgets (sizedBox, text and iconbutton) are equally spaced so the middle one is slightly moved on the right.
If I add another iconbutton and I'd like to have the text in center and the icons on the left it's not possible with this code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?:

```dart
    ...
Expanded(
   child: ListView.separated(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      controller: scrollController,
      physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int colIndex) {
         return Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
               Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, // add this line
                  children: [
                     Text(
                       "Some text",
                       textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                     ),
                     IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.settings_rounded),
                     ),
                  ],
               ),
               Text(
                  "Some other text",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
               ),
            ],
         ),
      },
   ),
),
...
```